# Rewrite eats GET variables - QSA rule doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, get

This is my .htaccess file.
The rewrite works, is but GET vars get lost.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dev.my-domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^pages/ /pages%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

So I https://my-domain.com/badPath?ID=666 is visible but

```
print_r($_GET);
```

says: Array()

The internet keeps telling me [QSA] ist the solution but for me it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your RewriteRule causing the problem. You can remove QSA. That only applies when you are modifying the query string, which you are not. Your query string is being passed through unmodified.

Change your RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule !^pages/ pages%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Removing QSA and the forward slash which is already provided by mod_rewrite, so don't double it up.

It must be some other rule, or something else, that is dropping the query string.

Comment: Ah thanks, I see. Well it's not this rule that is causing the parameter to disappear.

Comment: Well thank you. At least I can go look for the problem elsewhere now. *sigh*

Comment: Hope you find it easily. Please accept my answer when you can.

Comment: As soon as I crack the nut, I will. Still hope to help others avoid spaending satureday night on this.